# How to calculate the time complexity of this code?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

How to calculate the time complexity of the following algorithm?

```
int x =0;

      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j < n; ++j) {
            x++;
            n--;
        }
    }
```

I know that time complexity for nested for loops is equal to the number of times the innermost loop is executed.

like every nested loop that the outer loop is from 1 to n, it should run n times but here we have  `n--`  that makes the algorithm run in better order. actually, I wrote this code in IDE and I printed the final result of x after loops end for different n value and I saw that nearly n times takes that we jump into inner for loop.

so I think that the whole order of this algorithm is `O (n)` **but I am not sure**

can someone help me prove it completely?

Comment: Why not simply profile it with different sizes? This will give you a good indicator, if you're right. When you are sure, start to try to proof it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the time complexity with big O or big Theta, and let just calculate the upper bound and the lower bound, which are easier cases.

Consider the `inner for loop`, `n` will decrease half at the time, or `n` will become `n/2` every time go out of the `inner for loop` (you already know that right, because `j` increase 1 unit at the time, `n` decrease 1 unit at the time, so `j` and `n` will meet each other at the `middle n` or `n/2`). Things get complicated when we dont know when the code stops, `n = ?`, but we know that `n > 1`

Consider this below code (the upper bound):

```
int x =0;

      for (;n > 1;) {

        for (int j = 1; j < n; ++j) {
            x++;
            n--;
        }
    }
```

`n` will become `n/2` each iteration until `n = 1`, so the complexity of the obove code will be `n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... + 1 = O(n)`.

The lower bound is even easier, assume that the `inner for loop` runs only 1 iteration and the code finish, that 1 iteration gives us `n/2` operators. So the lower bound would be `O(n)`.

=> The complexity is `O(n)` overall.

I think the key of `upper - lower bound` method is leaving out some `complex - hard to calculate - unclear changing variable` in the code and compare it to the original one

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

The total number of times `n` is decreased cannot exceed its original value (`i` and `j` are never negative).

Since for each iteration of the inner loop `n` is decreased exactly once, this gives you upper bound on the number of times this runs, making your code `O(n)`.

You can also see this is a tight bound, since the first time the inner loops runs, it will stop when `i >= n`, which will happen after `~n/2` iteration, giving a lower bound of `Omega(n)` as well.